# How do solve this equation with dot product?

Tags: parametric

$$[(2,-7)+t(2,10)]\cdot n_1=0$$

$$\text{Solving for $t$, we find }t=\dfrac5{12}$$

$n_1=(1,1)$ or $(-1,-1)$.

How does $t=\dfrac5{12}$?

Comment: $(2,-7)+t(2,10)=(2+2t,-7+10t)$...

Answer (score 0):

$$(2+2t,-7+10t)\cdot (1,1)=2+2t-7+10t=0.$$
Then $-5=-12t$ and the result follows.
Same for $(-1,-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

This line tells you with $n_1=(1,1)$ or $n_1=-(1,1)$ that 
$$2+2t=-(-7+10t)$$
Which is simply
$$12t=5$$
and thus
$$t=\frac{5}{12}$$